# Unable to change ConfusionMatrix size

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I have got following very simple python code:

```
        from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay

        # Holdout method with 2/3 training
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(self.train, self.target, test_size=0.33)


        # train the k-NN
        classifier = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(k)
        classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

        # predict the test set on our trained classifier
        y_test_predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)
        
        ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions(y_test,y_test_predicted)
```

The thing is my predictions have several classes and the plotted matrix is just way to small to properly display the result... ( it gets automatically plotted only with this line inside a Jupyter notebook)

My question is simple. How do i increase the size of the confusion matrix using this method ?

I literally have searched dozens of sites now but its not leading anywhere.

They all seem to somehow involve matplotlib which i am just not intelligent enough to understand it seems.

I am am desperate at this point because the problem seems so simple but yet so impossible.

How do i increase the size of the plotted confusion matrix?

Comment: You should **really** learn some matplotlib. If you will do any data science, ML or other scienticif computing in python, that will be worth it. And in this case, the solution MUST involve matplotlib, since it is matplotlib that makes the confusion matrix. See answer from ThSorn below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `ax` with the size you want (in the below example, I set it to `(50,50)` and pass it to function as argument `ax` ) ?

```py
f,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(50,50))
ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions(y_test, y_pred, ax=ax)
```

Comment: figsize is in inches, so 50,50 is really really huge. but sure, it is not too small. :)

Comment: You are forever my hero. You managed to do the most basic thing of all which so many official docs and tutorials have failed...